# Oracle enforcing constraints on soft delete

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, constraints

I have a table (called Table A) that has an **alive** column. This column can be 1 or 0. If it is 0 then it means that it has been deleted. This is a soft delete.

The problem I have is that I want to verify foreign key constraints on rows in this table. If I was to delete a row from Table A then more often than not it would through foreign key constraints because of its relationship with other rows. This is good and expected. The problem I have is that as my deletions are soft (just updating a flag) I do not get any constraint checking when I delete. This means that I need to check the relationships manually.

Is there anyway I can add a constraint to an oracle table which uses the 1 and 0 as part of the integrity constraint? For example if I update **alive** column to 0 it will then hit the constraint and so will not allow the column to be changed to 0.

Can I do this somehow?

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a foreign key constraint. I think your best option would be a trigger. Would you like an example?

Comment: If you delete a row from table and get an error then exception is thrown. How do you update your flag? In separate process or during a delete? There is no such thing as 1 and 0 is part of integr. constraint. You can only add check constraint where your flag, for example, is in 1 or 0. You may also think of triggers that would update some values in some other tables if this make sense. Please post sample data, tables, data etc...

Comment: thanks for your comments. I was thinking of a trigger but was hoping I would be able to do it more simply with some constraint. Thanks for the help. I'll use a trigger instead...

Comment: I really can't tell what you want to happen here. Do you want to make sure that a soft delete cannot happen on a row that has child rows? What does "blow the constraint" mean?

Comment: This sort of problem is the reason why right thinking people abjure soft deletes in favour of hard deletes and journalling tables.

Comment: @DavidAldridge bad english from my point of view. I;ll update question to remove the "blow the constraint" to make it clearer. IN answer to your other question - yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a modelling perspective, in this case I'd lean towards APC's comment on moving the "soft deleted" rows to another table (e.g. a journal table) and using a hard delete.

Another option (not tested) is to include the soft-delete column in the referential constraint, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dept (
  dept_id number,
  alive number,
  constraint alive_ck check (alive in (0,1)),
  constraint dept_pk primary key (dept_id, alive),
  constraint dept_uk unique (dept_id)
);

CREATE TABLE emp (
  emp_id number,
  dept_id number,
  alive number,
  constraint emp_pk primary key (emp_id),
  constraint emp_dept_fk
    foreign key (dept_id, alive)
    references dept (dept_id, alive)
);
```

Notice that the dept table is unique over dept_id, but also has a constraint over (dept_id, alive) to allow the referential constraint from emp.

This means your application will now need to update all the emp rows at the same time when soft-deleting a dept - and if you don't code it, the constraint effectively ensures that the dept cannot be soft-deleted unless the emps are first deleted (or soft deleted - although you'd have to make the constraint deferrable for this to work).

Comment: I am inclined to upvote this answer as it is technically correct - but ACP's comment seems more helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I am starting to think the hard delete might be better. The composite key idea is a good one though. That's the sort of thing I was after. Thanks